# Query Form in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, contact-form

I need a query form on one of my wordpress pages.

The main concern here is that the user needs to select his/her Country, then State, then City/Village. 
I need to achieve the selective filtering functionality here.

**

> When the user selects country, the states from the selected country
>   only should be available in the next drop down list. Same should
>   happen with the City upon selection on State and so on.

** Please suggest me any plugin that can help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic hard coded option field demonstration for loading the next specific option field for the country's states.

I do recommend doing this with AJAX and your database but is far beyond the scope of this question.

HTML FORM:

```
<form action="submit.php" id="test">
  <select id="country">
    <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
    <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
    <option value="Russia">Russia</option>
  </select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

PHP SCRIPT, file name: submit.php

```
<?php
if ( isset ( $_POST['test'] ) ) {

  $country = $_POST['country'];
  if ( isset ( $country ) && $country == 'Russia') {
    get_template_part('russia_states'); // this includes in russia_states.php
  }
  elseif($country == 'Mexico'){
    get_template_part('mexico_states'); // this includes in mexico_states.php
  }
  elseif($country == 'Argentina'){
    get_template_part('argentina_states'); // this includes in argentina_states.php
  } 
}
?>
```

Each elseif statement there will be calling a new form file which will be written with the chosen country's states.

This is what argentina_states.php will have.

```
<form action="submit.php" id="states">
  <select id="argentina_states">
    <option value="Salta">Salta</option>
    <option value="Mendoza">Mendoza</option>
    <option value="Río_Negro">Río Negro</option>
   <!-- etc -->
  </select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort. Please suggest me some plugin to achieve this functionality as I am not a PHP Programmer.  If I have to code, I can do it in ten minutes in ASP.NET using C#. New to Wordpress, hence need a plugin like Contact Form 7.